# Icinga not expanding contactemail variable

Tags: nagios, icinga

I'd like to define a couple contacts that make use of the user variables out of resources.cfg like this:

```
define contact {
    contact_name                                      XXX
    use                                               generic-contact
    alias                                             YYY
    email                                             $USER100$
}
```

The variables exist but when I try to make use of `$CONTACTEMAIL$` I get back the literal string of `USER100`.

What am I missing here? I've tried a couple different methods of quoting the `$USER100$` both in the contact definition and the command itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [macro list](https://docs.icinga.com/latest/en/macrolist.html#validity), macros are only valid in the context of host/service checks, notifications, event handlers, and performance data.

In short: you can't.